# including ui-date is displaying error

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

i have included ui-date like below

```
<input ui-date>
```

Along with the following files :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/date.js"></script>
```

However I get the following errors:

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
    at Object.initDateWidget [as fn] (http://www.myDomain.com/app/lib/angular/date.js:48:19)

Any clue where I may be going wrong ?

Comment: Are you adding reference to angular library and angular UI library in your script file before date.js?

Comment: yeah..got those items..doesn't eliminate the error

Answer (score 0):

The angular-ui.js cdn that I was referencing was errorneous. Replacing that did the trick. However the whole process was quiet frustrating. Small things taking up too much time.